# MySQL get just one row duplicated result on select

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, join, select

I have the following select query. I want to avoid getting the duplicated "EN" row when "ES" row is present. Like prefer ES over EN.

```
SELECT s.soft_id,s.groupby,s.packageid,s.name,s.area,l.min,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT JSON_ARRAY(s.version,s.detailid,s.filesize,s.updatetime)) versions
FROM software s
INNER JOIN langs l ON s.lang_id=l.lang_id
INNER JOIN devices_type t ON (s.familylock_id=t.familylock_id OR (s.familylock_id=0 AND s.devicelock_id=t.device_type_id))
INNER JOIN devices d ON t.device_type_id=d.device_type_id
INNER JOIN users u ON d.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE s.groupby IN(1,2,3)
AND u.token="abc"
AND d.serialno="123456789" 
AND l.min IN("ES","EN")
GROUP BY s.soft_id,s.groupby,s.packageid,s.name,s.area,l.min ORDER BY s.name ASC
```

This is the example result. And i want to get rid of AUDI and AUTOSEARCH "EN" rows.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rpy.png)

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Exactly! Give it a try and see if you get the expected result.

Comment: You are misusing MySQL's notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY. Please read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `WHERE` condition to exclude a row with `l.min = 'EN'` if a row with `l.min = 'ES'` exists. You can do this using a `NOT EXISTS` clause; changing the

```
AND l.min IN("ES","EN")
```

condition to

```
AND (l.min = 'ES' OR
     l.min = 'EN' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                  FROM software s2
                                  JOIN langs l2 ON l2.lang_id = s2.lang_id
                                  WHERE s2.soft_id = s.soft_id 
                                    AND l2.min = 'ES')
     )
```

Small sample [demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/888596/3)

Comment: hi again @Nick . i replaced it but its not working, same result. i think the way is close but the sub-select should not be correct. langs table have all available langs stored, always. but software is where should search. if there are two repeated rows in my initial query, get only the prefered "ES"

Comment: @Febian that's what the `l2.lang_id = s.lang_id` in the subquery is for, it will restrict the values returned to those which match the specific software row.

Comment: there is a link in the previous comment where you can run the query with your suggested mod but the result is the same than my inital query

Comment: @Febian sorry about the lack of response, I've been away from my desk. I've corrected the query, please see my edit.

Comment: thank you. the query works. but it takes 1 sec on localhost vs the first query which takes 0.014s or 0.00 most times. i should not use it right? do you imagine other way?

Comment: @Febian that would depend what version of MySQL you are using. A `NOT EXISTS` clause is probably the most efficient way in MySQL 5.x

Comment: @Febian in MySQL 8 you could try a query like this one: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uR8uZztuZC5xrAJSfqvB7o/0

Comment: thank you nick. i was able to apply your fiddle to my code and it works great and awsome fast. same thant he inital query. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is the below helps? I could not validate the script as I don't have sample data but below idea should help you to set the priority.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=121eb77258dc7dabb13eed8abf39f10f)

```
WITH preference  AS
   (
      SELECT s.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY s.soft_id
      ORDER BY s.packageid,
         CASE
            WHEN l.min = 'ES'
            THEN 'A'
            ELSE 'B'
         END)  priority
      FROM software s
INNER JOIN langs l ON s.lang_id=l.lang_id
WHERE l.min IN("ES","EN")
   )
SELECT  *
FROM preference
WHERE priority = 1;
```